# Is it possible to simulate a big file upload HTTP request without selecting a file in axios?

Tags: javascript, http, file-upload, axios

I have this requirement where I need to test file size limit and right now it's manual, because files are too big to be included in the CI/CD.

I wonder if it's possible for me to simulate a big file upload (using stupid random bytes for example) with Axios?

Has anyone ever done it?

Comment: Create a fake "file" to upload using the File() constructor perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: @CBroe, that's interesting. But how can I create *fake bits*? I mean would it be just a random array of zeros and ones?

Comment: @CBroe, I tried `Array.from({length: 1_000_000_000}).fill(0)` and my Google Chrome simply hanged and got killed. :)))

Comment: Not sure how big you need your files to be, but you don't have to pass single integers, you can pass an array of string values as well for example. `new File(["0123456789".repeat(10000000)], "name")` still goes quickly on my Chrome console, with another 0 appended to the repeat factor I am getting "caught RangeError: Invalid string length" though. But you could fill an array with multiple such strings.

Comment: @CBroe, I assume `10_000_000` repeated over `0123456789` becomes 100MBs, am I right? I need at least 1 GigaByte of test data. Can I tenfold your code?

Comment: Not sure at which point you'll run into memory issues, you'd have to test it. I am guessing that the upload of a "normal" file probably allows the browser to read this in chunks, so that it doesn't have to keep all the file content in memory at the same time.

Comment: @CBroe, it seems that it's working. Thank you. Can you post your comment as an answer please, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and create a fake "file" using the [`File()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) constructor.

You can feed that with multiple different data types, it would perhaps make sense to start with string values in an array here - keeping the strings under the maximum allowed length, and adding as many as you need to reach your final required file size.

Something like

```
new File(["0123456789".repeat(10000000)], "name")
```

"filled up" to (about) the desired size by adding more such strings to the array.